# Visual Studio 2010 files modified warning dialog before recompile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compilation, dialog

by default VS 2010 when I run a c++ application, eventually shows a dialog that notify if a source file changed, before automatically recompile the solution.

Unfortunately I made that dialog not to show anymore, accidentally selecting the checkbox "do not show again" or something like that.

Does anyone know how could I restore that dialog?

Comment: There isnt such a checkbox present. Are you sure its not working?
The options i had were: Yes  Yes to all  No  No to all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Build and Run` dialog are a couple of options that control this kind of behavior.  I think you're looking for the "On Run, when projects are out of date" option; select "Prompt to build".